# Sprites aren't animating

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I've been trying to update enemy sprites in my game by creating a vector of pointers to enemy objects and then using an update function to animate the sprites belonging to the objects. Although the enemy sprites are displayed on the screen, they won't get updated so they look as though they're frozen.

Here's how I've written my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<math.h>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
#include "Enemy.h"


sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1920, 1080), "Zombie game", sf::Style::Default);

std::vector<Enemy*>enemies;

int main()
{

    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    sf::Clock clock;

    Enemy *enemy = new Enemy();
    enemy->init("Assets/graphics/zombieSpriteSheetWalk.png", 4, 1.0f, sf::Vector2f(200.0f, 200.0f), sf::Vector2i(100, 107));
    enemies.push_back(enemy);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed || event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) window.close();
        }

        sf::Time dt = clock.restart();

        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++)
        {
            Enemy *enemy = enemies[i];
            enemy->update(dt.asSeconds());
        }

        window.clear();

        for (Enemy* enemy : enemies) window.draw(enemy->getSprite());

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Enemy.h file:

```
#pragma once
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy();
    ~Enemy();

    void init(std::string textureName, int frameCount, float animDuration, sf::Vector2f position, sf::Vector2i spriteSize);

    void update(float dt);
    sf::Sprite& getSprite();
    void test();
private:

    sf::Texture m_texture;
    sf::Sprite m_sprite;
    sf::Vector2f m_position;

    int m_frameCount; //no. of frames in animation
    float m_animDuration; //How long animation lasts (speed)
    float m_elapsedTime; //keeps track of how long game has been running
    sf::Vector2i m_spriteSize; //Size of each frame
};
```

Enemy.cpp file:

```
#include "Enemy.h"

Enemy::Enemy()
{
}


Enemy::~Enemy()
{
}

void Enemy::init(std::string textureName, int frameCount, float animDuration, sf::Vector2f position, sf::Vector2i spriteSize)
{
    m_position = position;

    m_frameCount = frameCount;
    m_animDuration = animDuration;

    m_spriteSize = spriteSize;

    m_texture.loadFromFile(textureName.c_str()); 
    m_sprite.setTexture(m_texture);
    m_sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, m_spriteSize.x, m_spriteSize.y));//sets which part of sprite sheet we want to display
m_sprite.setPosition(m_position);
    m_sprite.setOrigin((m_texture.getSize().x / frameCount) - 25.0f, m_texture.getSize().y / 2);
}

void Enemy::update(float dt)
{
    m_elapsedTime += dt;
    int animFrame = static_cast<int>((m_elapsedTime / m_animDuration) * m_frameCount) % m_frameCount; //calculates current animation frame number. static_class converts float to int
    m_sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(animFrame * m_spriteSize.x, 0, m_spriteSize.x, m_spriteSize.y)); //updates part of sprite sheet to be displayed
}


sf::Sprite& Enemy::getSprite()
{
    return m_sprite;

}
```

Comment: "The problem is with the way I'm using the pointers" -- and what exactly is the problem. The only problem that's evident from the shown code is that the vector contains only one value or pointer.

Comment: There's no reason to think that having only one enemy is a problem. Sounds like a great position to be in!

Comment: _"The problem is with the way I'm using pointers"_. Doesn't look that way to me. That's why you need to create a [mcve].

Comment: @SamVarshavchik But why would it be a problem if the vector only contained one pointer? In the for loop I'm iterating through all pointers inside the vector, right? So shouldn't the update function work on that one pointer to the Enemy object?

Comment: @Hasnat123 Yes.

Comment: Sure, it would. But you seem to be expecting a metric ton of enemies. As shown, the code only creates one.

Comment: It's obviously a cut down example, Sam - can we focus on the real problem? (And nothing in the question alludes to "a metric ton of enemies" you've just made that up)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes in my actual game I've tried to use more enemies but the same problem occurred.

Comment: Then you need to fully explain what your "problem" is. The only thing that anyone else on stackoverflow.com can see is whatever you put in your question, and there's nothing in the question that fully explains what the problem is. The problem could be in whatever's in `update()`. How do you expect anyone to help you with code that's not shown? Just because `update()` works if a vector does not get used to manage those pointers doesn't mean that it's bug free. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your code, which is why you must show a [mre].

Comment: I'm quite new to stack overflow and coding in general, so I'm unaware of how I can make my code any simpler. I will edit my question to include the update function

Comment: As I said at the top, you need to construct a [mcve] that (in some way) demonstrates your object's state not being updated as you intended for it to be. You can abstract away all the graphics parts of that and just use `cout` to show variables that you wished to be changed, not changing. You'll probably find the bug by doing this but, if you don't, we'll have enough information to help. This is not specific to Stack Overflow or to coding; whenever asking someone a question, about anything, they need enough information to answer it! Good luck and give me a ping if you get a mcve.

Answer (score 0):

## You're always at time 0

From the [SFML Clock header](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/86672a37246100f40077e692bc7130a8e4e87d2c/include/SFML/System/Clock.hpp#L65):

```cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// \brief Restart the clock
///
/// This function puts the time counter back to zero.
/// It also returns the time elapsed since the clock was started.
///
/// \return Time elapsed
///
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Time restart();
```

### Possible Fix

1. Use `sf::Clock` for `dt` instead of `sf::Time` and move it out of the event loop (you want it to accumulate as the program runs, not reset to 0 every time through.
2. Replace:

   ```cpp
   enemy->update(dt.asSeconds());
   ```

   with

   ```cpp
   enemy->update(dt.getElapsedTime());
   ```

### More Notes

I'm making some assumptions in this answer of types because your example was incomplete. One big omission you made was not including the `class Enemy` definition (especially the types of the member variables).

Based on the definition of `Enemy::init`, I would assume it would contain the following:

```cpp
class Enemy
{
    float m_elapsedTime;
    float m_animDuration;
    int m_frameCount;
    ...
```

However, those definitions result in the following compilation error in your version of `Enemy::update`:

```
enemy.cpp: In member function ‘void Enemy::update(float)’:
enemy.cpp:14:88: error: invalid operands of types ‘float’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator%’
int animFrame = static_cast<int>(((m_elapsedTime / m_animDuration) * m_frameCount) % m_frameCount);
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

#### floats

You don't want to run animations that are a function of game time if game time is a float. The reason why not is that floating point numbers have different precision in different value ranges, the closer the number is to 0, the more precision you have, and the farther you are from 0, the less precision you have. This means that as game time progresses, your animations will not run at a constant rate (they will appear to be choppy, inconsistent, not smooth after enough time has elapsed).

A better approach would be to have an wrapping animation counter that adds the delta times and then wraps back to zero (or perhaps wraps back to 0 + some remainder, perhaps using a function like [fmod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod)). This will make sure your animation frame rate is consistent for the entire duration of the game.

Comment: I have now added all the code related to the question. Hope this helps